# Simple stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Solve the following stochastic differential equation:
$$
dX_t=X_t\,dt+dW_t.
$$
Thank you very much for help! I even don't know where to start...

Answer (score 4):

The usual tool used here is Ito's Formula. To use it, you'll want to propose a possible solution, say
$$X_t = e^{t}\left(X_0 + \int_0^t e^{-s} \, dW_s\right),$$
and use Ito, by defining a function, say, $g(t,y)$ that is a function of deterministic $t$ and stochastic $y$. For a nice introduction to SDEs I half-heartedly recommend Oksendal.

Indeed, I do not respond directly to your question. Readily available is not my intuition about generating this solution (I happened to have it "in my back pocket"), but I think it derives from intuition you might have developed in ODE (notice the exponential term, a common term in the solution to ODEs).

Comment: are you sure? Let's calculate $d\,X_t$ for your $X_t$, assuming that $X_0=0$: $$d\,X_t=-e^{-t}\cdot\int_{0}^{t}e^s\,dW_s+e^{-t}e^t\,dW_t$$ and this is not $X_t$ but $-X_t$. Am I right?

Comment: So finally the solution is $-X_t$, not $X_t$, am I right? But I am not sure my calculations are correct: what about the equality $$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t}e^s \,dW_s=e^t\,dW_t?$$

Comment: Indeed, the notation you give is just shorthand. The right hand side is shorthand for the left.

Comment: Soren, thank you for assuring me about correctness of my calculation - now I understand it. You have also to edit $e^s$ into $e^{-s}$ in your first answer.

Answer (score 4):

(Shreve: *Stochastic Calculus for Finance Volume II*, Exercise 4.8). This is a specific case of the Vasicek SDE,
$$
dR_t = (\alpha - \beta R_t)dt + \sigma dW_t.
$$

Use Ito's formula to compute 
$$d(e^{\beta t} R_t)= \beta e^{\beta t} R_tdt + e^{\beta t} dR_t = \cdots $$
the right side will not involve $R_t$.
Integrate this answer to obtain the solution.

Comment: Outside of finance the [Vasicek model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasicek_model) is also known as an [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein–Uhlenbeck_process). I believe the analytical solution is first due to [Doob 1946](http://venus.usc.edu/PAPERS/MultiScaleMechanics/Doob-BrownianMotionStochasticEquations.pdf).

Comment: Hi,  what is $R_t$ here?  Is it just any random variable?

Comment: @MattPhillips, $R_t$ is an unknown stochastic process that you are trying to solve for.